# No sound in Chrome in fresh 15.04 install

Tags: sound, 15.04, google-chrome

Sound works in other programs including Firefox and, bizarrely, Chromium. Chrome does not appear under applications in Sound settings. NOT a flash issue, as non-flash sounds play. NOT an NPAPI issue, as it is enabled by default. Moving the config file to google-chrome_bak does NOT work. Absolutely new 15.04 install, not an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fresh install of 15.04 on my Thinkpad T450s. I fixed it by installing Pipelight: http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html